# How many times it is ordered a IENumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I know that when I iterate a IEnumerable, I iterate the source collection, so if I modified the source collection in the next iteration of the IEnumerable it has in count the modificaction.

So I am wondering how it affects that when I have a ordered IEnumerable.

For example, if I have this:

```
List<MyType> myNoOrderedList //add my items

IEnumerable<MyType> myOrderedIEnumerable = myNoOrderedList
  .OrderBy(x => x.Property);

foreach(MyType in myOrderedIEnumerable)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Supose that I have 3 elements in the list, in each iteration on IEnumerable, the list is ordered or only the list is ordered once?

What happen if in "Do something" I add or remove an item? The IEnumerable has initial ordered items or has to order again to has account the modification of the list?

Comment: AFAIK the LINQ generated enumerables will be re-enumarated each time so if you modify the base list and iterate the order will still be correct. However it's trivial to check this out yourself.

Comment: Just run the code and check it by yourself  - will be much faster then asking it here ;)

Comment: _What happen if in "Do something" I add or remove an item?_ - you will get very fast answer when you run it - in format of Exception

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmRx2q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers:

1. At most once (on the *materialization* if any)
2. Since you've *materialized* the `myOrderedIEnumerable` any modifications of the initial `myNoOrderedList` will not be seen:

Simplified example:

```
 List<string> initial = new List<String>() {
   "a", "z", "e", "d";
 };

 // Nothing will be done at this point (no ordering)
 var ordered = initial.
   .OrderBy(x => x.Property);

 // ordered has not materialized here, so it'll feel Addition
 initial.Add("y"); // <- will be added into ordered 

 // Here on the first loop ordered will be materialized and since
 // initial and ordered are different collection now, we can modify 
 // initial without changing ordered
 foreach (var item in ordered) {
   if (item == "a") {
     initial.Add("b");
     initial.Remove("z");
   } 

   Console.WriteLine(item);
 }
```

Outcome:

```
a
d
e
y <- before materialization
z
```

**Edit**: Please, notice, that materization is a *tricky thing*: it may be called:

1. Immediately, at the declaration e.g. after `.ToList()`, `.Any()`, `.FirstOrDefault()`
2. On the first item e.g. `.OrderBy` (your case)
3. Never e.g. `.Where()`, `.SkipWhile()` - see Magnus's comment

*Linq* is lazy and perfom materialization as late as possible.

Comment: But if the query looked different, only contained a `where` for example it would effect the foreach loop. So "materialization" behaves differently depending on the query.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, can you expand this answer to a multithreading scenario or at least a comment? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sharky: *bad news*: `List<T>` (`initial`) is not *thread-safe*, that's why *multithreading scenario* is not for it (you are going to have unstable outcome) if you try to modify the list

Comment: @Magnus: You are quite right, thank you! Linq is lazy and that's why nmaterialization is tricky; this fact worth mentioning.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for the response Dmitry!

Answer (score 2):

> Supose that I have 3 elements in the list, in each iteration on IEnumerable, the list is ordered or only the list is ordered once?

**According to your current code, only once.**
The list is ordered every time you get an enumerator.
Your `foreach` statement will be compiled into `try..finally` with only one enumerator which will be used to iterate through collection.

> What happen if in "Do something" I add or remove an item? The IEnumerable has initial ordered items or has to order again to has account the modification of the list?

If you add or remove item from `myNoOrderedList` before you acquire an enumerator from `IOrderedEnumerable`, then it will be included into sorted result.
If you do it after you have started to enumerate a sorted collection, then it **won't affect your active enumeration in any way**, because sorted items are buffered and returned from a buffer.

However, keep in mind, that if you could add or remove an item to enumerating collection (`miOrderedIEnumerable` in your case), then you would get **`InvalidOperationException`** saying "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".

Comment: Sorry, but the second answer is not correct. You can't change `miOrderedIEnumerable` within the `foreach` but you can call `Add`, `RemoveAt`, `Clear`...  on `myNoOrderedList`. However, when `myNoOrderedList` is modified, `miOrderedIEnumerable` will not be changed.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Of course, you are right, my bad :( I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the result of `OrderBy` is needed, a [buffered **copy** of the source is sorted](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,23c6be2fd074160a). For example:

```
int[] array = { 2, 1, 3 };
var ordered = array.OrderBy(x => x);

foreach (int i in ordered)
{
    array[1] = 0;
    Debug.Write(i);             // 123
}

foreach (int i in ordered)
    Debug.Write(i);             // 023
```